# Rails - Assign foreign key to an associated record that is created in the same form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is it possible in Rails3.2 to assign a foreign key `foo_id` to a record in the `Bar` table when both the `Foo` and `Bar` objects are created in the same create action?

e.g.

```
@whatever = Whatever.new
@whatever.build_foo
@whatever.build_bar
```

Is it possible to do an `after_create` callback to update the `foo_id` attribute after the create action has been run?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is possible provided the association between `Bar` and `Foo` has been set correctly.

```
@whatever = Whatever.new
@whatever.build_foo
@whatever.build_bar
@whatever.bar.foo = @whatever.foo
@whatever.save
```